# State Preservation and Restoration on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have been making an application for iOS, in which I make use of State Preservation and Restoration to wake my app back up, when I come within range of a previously connected Bluetooth device.

Now that I am trying to make the same app on Android, I am having a very hard time figuring out how to do the same thing on this platform?

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Android has callbacks that are invoked when your app is going away which you can use to save state. When the app is "recreated", you can then check to see if you have a saved instance and restore from that. Take a look at:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

You should also consider reading more on general Activity LifeCycle.